# Unity Gain Clipping Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, distortion, voltage-clipping, guitar-pedal

Please see the image below:

[image]

This is an idea for a unity gain clipping circuit to be used
in a guitar effects unit as a 'distortion' pedal.

Some percentage of a peak detector output voltage feeds into the reference voltage of a clamp.

If the input signal were compressed, the clipping would be relatively uniform. Or if the peak detection capacity were discharged quickly enough.

Could someone please:

1. Tell me if this idea is idiotic?
2. Tell me if the polarities of the opamp inputs are correct?
3. Suggest values for the RC network on the peak detectors?

Comment: OD808's clipping circuit without parallel RC network works better (Parallel RC network provides soft clipping). You can Google "OD808 schematic".

Comment: I removed your request for having _other people_ simulate your circuit, while editing the markup. If you can draw your circuit, you can simulate it yourself.

Comment: VTC - The 2, 3, and 4 questions here are basically asking for a design consultancy to complete the circuit design. This site is not that. Good god even any engineer realizes that you do your own circuit simulations - or pay someone to do it.

Comment: @pipe I have no oscilloscope, nor do I have access to any simulation software that regulars on this board have.

Comment: @Richard you can download LtSpice for free. A lot of people use that.

Comment: @Rohat You'll notice that the OD808 uses a pretty standard hard diode clipping system, and that requires the opamps to have a gain of more than 1. I want a distortion unit that requires no gain setting, it just gives optimal clipping at any volume.

Comment: I don't see that this idea is any different to using a guitar/microphone compressor followed by a distortion pedal that can cut into the almost constant amplitude sound level. Go down a geetar shop and get some gizmos out and try them to see if it sounds good or "idiotic". I expect it'll sound ok but not earth shattering.

Comment: Well.. this is just the start. The next step is to split the incoming signal into bands, and distort each band separately.
The resulting pedal will have only 5 faders on it, and they will be wet/dry. There will be no gain, or volume knobs.

Comment: Define "optimal clipping." Optimal is whatever the guitar player thinks sounds good.  Part of clipping is that it doesn't clip all sounds equally.  A loud sound might get chopped in half amplitude wise, but a quieter sound might not get clipped at all.  It looks like you are trying for some "clip set percentage of amplitude" regardless of what the amplitude is.  You might want to use something like puredata to simulate that effect before you build it.

Comment: One thing for sure, you cannot monitor (peak detect) the node that you are clipping.

Comment: @JRE "optimal" is whatever I decide it is at the time when I assign the filter values. The intention is not to let the user decide what optimal is. The finished circuit will have a 'sound' that you either like or do not. The idea is to avoid fluctuations in the level of clipping by splitting the input into frequency bands, each of which is clipped 'optimally'. I could use a compander to keep the level of clipping more constant, but the filtering is a form of compression in itself really. Thanks for the puredata tip. that looks interesting.

Comment: @rioraxe Wow.. yes. Now you've said it that sounds obvious. I'll need another input buffer..